# Proving $(\sigma(A_n))_{n\in I}$ independent $\iff$ $(A_n)_{n\in I}$ independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Consider

**Definition of independence of events:** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(A_n)_{n\in I}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ a family of events in $\mathcal{A}$. We say that the events are independent  if

$\forall J\subseteq I , J$ finite : $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j)=\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb{P}(A_j)$

**Definition of independence of $\sigma$-algebras:** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in I}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ a collection of sub-$\sigma-$algebras in $\mathcal{A}$. We say that the $\sigma-$algebras are independent , if

$\forall J\subseteq I , J$ finite  and $\forall B_j \in \mathcal{F_j}$: $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j)=\prod_{j\in J}\mathbb{P}(B_j)$

I was given the following proposition that I am trying to prove

**Proposition**

$(\sigma(A_n))_{n\in I}$ independent  $\iff$ $(A_n)_{n\in I}$ independent

where for each n, $\sigma(A_n)$ is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by $A_n$, that is $\sigma(A_n)=\{\emptyset,\Omega,A_n,A_n^C\}$

**My try:**

The $(\Leftarrow)$ is easy: In each $\mathcal{F}_j=\sigma(A_j)$ I can  take$ B_j=A_j$ and I have the definition for independece of events.

I am having trouble with the$(\Rightarrow)$ part.

Some facts that I know that may be helpful :

(1)If $A , B$ are independent, so are $A^C$ with $B$ or  $B^C$ with $A$   or $A^C$ with $B^C$.

(2) If $\{B_1,B_2....B_n\} $are independent, so are $B_j$ and $\bigcap_{k\neq j}B_k$ , $k,j \le n$

**How do I finish the proof?** I have searched here and there but I only found partial answers saying to prove other things first that I was unable to.

As a side thing why is the accepted answer in this post [Sigma algebras generated by independent sets of events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180887/sigma-algebras-generated-by-independent-sets-of-events) which deals with the same proposition I am asking about says the proposition is false and gives a counterexample. Perhaps I am misreading something, but it looks to me that

"$ (\Omega, \Sigma , \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \subseteq \Sigma$ independant subsets. Then $\sigma A(\mathcal{A})$ and $\sigma A(\mathcal{B})$ are independent sigma algebras."

is the same proposition as mine(in the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction) with the notation being the only difference. I think he denotes generated $\sigma$-algebra of a subset$ \mathcal{B} $ with $\sigma A(\mathcal{B})$

**EDIT:**

---

Following the suggestion in the comments
By finite induction:
If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent then $B_1 $is chosen  $\in \sigma(A_1)=\{\emptyset,\Omega,A_1,A_1^C\}$ and $B_2$ is chosen  $\in \sigma(A_2)=\{\emptyset,\Omega,A_2,A_2^C\}$ and I want to prove that $\mathbb{P}(B_1\cap B_2)=\mathbb{P}(B_1)\cap\mathbb{P}(B_2) $. Every time one of the chosen events is $\emptyset,\Omega$ it is easy to see the statement holds true. Otherwise, it is true by fact number (1) above.

Now we suppose that if $A_1,...A_{k-1}$ are independent, $\sigma(A_1),...\sigma(A_{k-1})$ are independent. And want to prove that if $A_1,...A_{k}$ are independent, $\sigma(A_1),...\sigma(A_{k})$  are independent. Let $B_j \in \sigma_(A_j)$ and consider $J=\{1,2,....,k\}$, $i \in J$

$\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{j=1}^{j=k}B_j)=\mathbb{P}(B_i\cap \bigcap_{j=1, j\neq i}^{j=k} B_j)$

The statement is true if $B_i= \Omega$ or $B_i= \emptyset$. Otherwise by   fact number (2) above, $B_i$  is independent from $\bigcap_{j=1, j\neq i}^{j=k}B_j$     so...

$\mathbb{P}(B_i\cap \bigcap_{j=1, j\neq i}^{j=k}B_j) =\mathbb{P}(B_i)\mathbb{P} (\bigcap_{j=1, j\neq i}^{j=k}B_j )$

and by inductive hypothesis

$=\mathbb{P}(B_i) \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^{j=k}\mathbb{P}(B_j) =\prod_{j=1}^{j=k}\mathbb{P}(B_j) $

which means that the $B_j, j=1,...,k$ are independent and therefore the $\sigma(A_j), j=1,...,k$ are independent

Comment: Can you do the case with just two of them?  $A_1$ and $A_2$.  Then do the case of $n$ events, for $n \in \mathbb N$.  Finally, reduce the infinite case to this.

Comment: @GEdgar I am following your suggestion, can you check it? I am not sure if this is induction and if so strong induction or weak induction